# Module not found: 'redux'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have create a new react application using `create-react-app` cli.
Then i have added the `'react-redux'` library using `npm install --save react-redux`.

In `package.json` I have:

```
"react-redux": "^4.4.5"
```

Unfortunately, the app doesn't compile and it complains with:

```
Error in ./~/react-redux/lib/utils/wrapActionCreators.js
Module not found: 'redux' in C:\Users\Salman\Desktop\Courses\Internship\React\Youtube-Front-End\node_modules\react-redux\lib\utils

 @ ./~/react-redux/lib/utils/wrapActionCreators.js 6:13-29
```

I have no idea what does it mean?

Here is the complete container:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class BookList extends Component{
  renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map((book)=>{
          <li key={book.title} >{book.title}</li>
        });
    }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    books:state.books
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

Here is complete `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Youtube-Front-End",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "youtube-api-search": "0.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You need to install react-redux but also redux library.

```
npm install --save redux
```

Comment: shorthand... npm i -S redux

Comment: it is a devdependencie or a dependenci like react?

Comment: No, normal dependency

Comment: no need to put the --save. `npm install --save redux` and `npm install install redux` are the same (`--save` is the default option) [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: $ npm i -S redux
# OR
$ yarn add redux

Comment: Note: My own experience was that I ran `npm i --save redux redux-react axios redux-thunk`, where `redux-react` wasn't right, it should have been `react-redux`. A very handy warning came up to tell me that I "...meant to install react-redux." So, I did that and then I was getting this error w/o looking at my package.json. So, yes, this answer is correct, but as a note to community, if one package in `npm install` attempt fails, the whole thing roles back.

Answer (score 23):

`react-redux` internally uses `Action, ActionCreator, AnyAction, Dispatch, Store` these interfaces form `redux` package.

the moment you call

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

`react-redux` try to make use of all these interfaces from `redux` package. which is not present at the moment.

So you may have to install `react-redux` package along with `redux` since both have dependency.

```
 npm install --save redux react-redux
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command:

using npm

```
npm install redux --save
```

using yarn

```
yarn add redux
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `moduleResolution` to **node** at `tsconfig.json`

Example:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge while working with Visual Studio Code (VSC) IDE.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
```

The 'redux' package was being resolved from another place all together, as a dependency within some typescript packages.

I ran `yarn add redux@3.7.2` (with the VSC terminal) to re-install the package. Note that i had the exact version within my `package.json` as a dependency, and this helps yarn to link the dependencies faster since my goal was not to upgrade redux yet.

Answer (score 1):

I put my all redux related files to src/redux folder and after some search, I found that this folder name can cause conflicts. After changing the folder name everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me in typescript it worked as follows:

```
yarn add @types/redux @types/react-redux
```

(or with `npm` try: `npm install add @types/redux @types/react-redux`)

Answer (score 0):

Just install react-redux if it is not present in package.json
using

> npm i react-redux

or install redux if it is not there in package.json

> npm i redux

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-redux but also a redux library, both are kind of dependent on each other. Don't forget to import it.

```
npm install --save redux
```

Answer (score -1):

using npm :

npm install redux --save

using yarn :

yarn add redux